# hyperref: different color for TOC links and for crossreferences

Tags: hyperref

I am using below code to create a document with clickable table of content and cross-references:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{color,hyperref}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0, 0, .7}

\hypersetup{colorlinks,
            breaklinks,
            linkcolor=darkblue, % color used for in-document links
            urlcolor=darkblue,
            anchorcolor=darkblue,
            citecolor=darkblue}

\title{Title here}
\author{Author, First Name}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{Introduction} \label{sec:intro}
    \lipsum[2] The \textit{Section} \ref{sec:second} does things.

\section{Second section} \label{sec:second}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

I want different link colors for the links in the TOC (`black`) and for cross-references (`darkblue`). However changing `linkcolor` alters both. Is there a way to manipulate them separately?

Comment: So you want one color for in-document links when they are in the ToC and one for in-document links after the ToC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you right, you want to have `linkcolor` change after the ToC, correct? Well just call `\hypersetup` a second time after the ToC was typeset:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{color,hyperref}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0, 0, .7}

\hypersetup{colorlinks,
            breaklinks,
            linkcolor=black, % color used for in-document links
            urlcolor=darkblue,
            anchorcolor=darkblue,
            citecolor=darkblue}

\title{Title here}
\author{Author, First Name}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\hypersetup{colorlinks,
    breaklinks,
    linkcolor=darkblue, % color used for in-document links
    urlcolor=darkblue,
    anchorcolor=darkblue,
    citecolor=darkblue}

\newpage

\section{Introduction} \label{sec:intro}
    \lipsum[2] The \textit{Section} \ref{sec:second} does things.

\section{Second section} \label{sec:second}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```